# SQL Server : compare dates between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm working with SQL server 2016 and I can't figure out how to build that query.

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
ID  EntryTime               ResultTime
1   2016-05-02 13:30:00     2016-05-02 21:50:00
2   2016-05-02 14:45:00     2016-05-02 22:00:00
3   2016-05-02 16:30:00     2016-05-02 22:21:00
4   2016-05-03 01:00:00     2016-05-03 03:33:00
5   2016-05-03 10:30:00     2016-05-04 07:47:00
6   2016-05-03 12:30:00     2016-05-03 22:45:00
7   2016-05-04 11:30:00     2016-05-05 21:30:00
8   2016-05-04 12:30:00     2016-05-04 22:58:00
9   2016-05-04 13:30:00     2016-05-04 23:04:00
10  2016-05-04 13:45:00     2016-05-04 22:59:00
11  2016-05-04 14:00:00     2016-05-04 22:59:00
12  2016-05-04 14:15:00     2016-05-04 23:04:00
13  2016-05-04 17:45:00     2016-05-04 21:47:00
14  2016-05-05 23:30:00     2016-05-06 03:25:00
15  2016-05-05 23:45:00     2016-05-06 03:30:00
16  2016-05-06 00:00:00     2016-05-06 03:32:00
17  2016-05-06 00:15:00     2016-05-06 03:31:00
18  2016-05-06 00:30:00     2016-05-06 03:25:00
19  2016-05-06 00:45:00     2016-05-06 02:50:00
20  2016-05-06 01:00:00     2016-05-06 03:25:00
```

I want to select just the rows that the entry datetime is after the last chosen result datetime.

For example: the result time for line 1 is "2016-05-02 21:50:00" so the next row will be line 4 because this is the first line that the entry time is after the result time that was last selected, the next line suppose to be after the result time of line 4 (After "2016-05-03 03:33:00") so the next line will be line 5.

The requested result is:

```
ID  EntryTime               ResultTime
1   2016-05-02 13:30:00     2016-05-02 21:50:00
4   2016-05-03 01:00:00     2016-05-03 03:33:00
5   2016-05-03 10:30:00     2016-05-04 07:47:00
7   2016-05-04 11:30:00     2016-05-05 21:30:00
14  2016-05-05 23:30:00     2016-05-06 03:25:00
```

Comment: your desired output is unclear.. can u be more elaborate...

Comment: I think you are the only one knows the result

Comment: Interesting... Definitely it can be done in WHILE loop, but as single SELECT, not sure...

Comment: What is the version of your SQL Server? Please add a corresponding tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this is by using a recursive CTE to get the next row. For example,

```
with cte as (
    select *
    from myTable
    where id = 1
    union all
    select t.*
    from myTable t
    cross join cte
    where t.id = (
        select id 
        from (
            select id, row_number() over (order by id) rn 
            from myTable 
            where entrytime > cte.resulttime) z 
        where rn = 1)
    )
select * from cte;
```

EDIT: For multiple "symbols", here's a method that would work (with example data).

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (Symbol CHAR(3), EntryTime DATETIME, ResultTime DATETIME)
INSERT @myTable VALUES ('AAA','2016-05-02 13:30:00','2016-05-02 21:50:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-02 14:45:00','2016-05-02 22:00:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-02 16:30:00','2016-05-02 22:21:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-03 01:00:00','2016-05-03 03:33:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-03 10:30:00','2016-05-04 07:47:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-03 12:30:00','2016-05-03 22:45:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-04 11:30:00','2016-05-05 21:30:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-04 12:30:00','2016-05-04 22:58:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-04 13:30:00','2016-05-04 23:04:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-04 13:45:00','2016-05-04 22:59:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-04 14:00:00','2016-05-04 22:59:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-04 14:15:00','2016-05-04 23:04:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-04 17:45:00','2016-05-04 21:47:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-05 23:30:00','2016-05-06 03:25:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-05 23:45:00','2016-05-06 03:30:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-06 00:00:00','2016-05-06 03:32:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-06 00:15:00','2016-05-06 03:31:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-06 00:30:00','2016-05-06 03:25:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-06 00:45:00','2016-05-06 02:50:00')
,('AAA','2016-05-06 01:00:00','2016-05-06 03:25:00')
,('BBB','2016-05-02 01:00:00','2016-05-02 03:01:00')
,('BBB','2016-05-02 02:00:00','2016-05-02 03:05:00')
,('BBB','2016-05-02 03:00:00','2016-05-02 03:40:00')
,('BBB','2016-05-02 04:00:00','2016-05-02 04:01:00')
,('BBB','2016-05-02 05:00:00','2016-05-03 07:00:00')
,('BBB','2016-05-02 06:00:00','2016-05-02 07:00:00')
,('BBB','2016-05-03 06:00:00','2016-05-03 07:05:00')
,('BBB','2016-05-04 06:01:00','2016-05-04 07:08:00')
,('BBB','2016-05-04 06:07:00','2016-05-04 07:52:00')
,('BBB','2016-05-05 06:00:00','2016-05-05 07:49:00')
,('CCC','2016-05-05 06:00:00','2016-05-05 07:04:00')
,('CCC','2016-05-05 06:05:00','2016-05-05 06:55:00')
,('CCC','2016-05-05 07:00:00','2016-05-05 07:10:00')
,('CCC','2016-05-05 07:06:00','2016-05-05 08:05:00')
,('CCC','2016-05-05 08:00:00','2016-05-05 08:15:00')
,('CCC','2016-05-05 08:09:00','2016-05-05 09:00:00');

WITH myTable AS (
    SELECT Symbol, EntryTime, ResultTime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Symbol ORDER BY EntryTime) RN
    FROM @myTable)
, CTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    WHERE RN = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.*
    FROM CTE
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT Symbol, EntryTime, ResultTime, RN
        FROM (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EntryTime) RN2
            FROM myTable
            WHERE Symbol = CTE.Symbol
            AND EntryTime > CTE.ResultTime) Z
        WHERE RN2 = 1) T
    )
SELECT Symbol, EntryTime, ResultTime--, RN [ID?]
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Symbol;
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to do it by recursive CTE, though a simple cursor that looks through each row once is likely to be more efficient than self-joins.

Comment: MAXRECURSION with zero value should be specified, right?  Default is 100.

Comment: Perfect answer, fast and efficient, I just changed "order by id" in line 12 to "order by EntryTime" because ID is not always in the entry time order.
**But I have another issue**. In this table I have 50 different symbols so I made it to work with the first symbol, How can I run over all the 50 symbols (each symbol have to start over from the first entry time)

Comment: What do you mean by "symbols"? Could you edit the OP with an example?

Comment: what is OP?
I mean  that I have another column called symbol, all the data I gave here is one symbol so let's say that the all rows hold the value "AAA" for the Symol column, and I have another set of dates with Symbol "BBB" for each row and another set of dates with symbol "CCC" and so on...
so the question is how I get all the results that your answer gave me but now with Symbols for each set

Comment: You would use partitioning with the row number function to do that. I'll edit in an example.

Comment: ZLK - Works perfect... It became slowly (40 minutes instead of 5 seconds - 500,000 records) but it giving the right answer. If I could I would give you more scores. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hmm. It's possible the execution time could be improved with the right indexing, but that really depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
select *
from @t t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from @t t2
    where t2.id < t1.id and t2.resultDate > t1.entryDate
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not quite good. It taking in account the last result time in the table even if it's not selected.

Comment: For example: If the result time in one row is 10:00:00 and the next line the entry time is 9:00:00 and the result time is 11:00 it suppose to skip that line and not using its result time because the entry time is before the  last result time. your answer now will look for the next entry time after 11:00:00 and not after 10:00:00 as it suppose to

Answer (score 1):

I think sometimes cursor is the answer

```
CREATE FUNCTION getSelected
(    
)
RETURNS @res TABLE 
(
    id int, EntryTime DATETIME, ResultTime DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @idC int;
    declare @ResultTimeC DATETIME;
    declare @EntryTimeC DATETIME;
    declare @lastNextDate DATETIME;

    DECLARE Iterator CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD 
    FOR SELECT id, EntryTime, ResultTime FROM dbo.tt1 order by EntryTime, id
    OPEN Iterator
    WHILE 1=1 BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM Iterator INTO @idC, @EntryTimeC, @ResultTimeC
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS < 0 BREAK 

        if(@lastNextDate is null or @lastNextDate < @EntryTimeC) begin
            set @lastNextDate = @ResultTimeC;
            insert into @res (id, EntryTime, ResultTime) values (@idC, @EntryTimeC, @ResultTimeC);
        end;            
    END
    CLOSE Iterator
    DEALLOCATE Iterator;

    RETURN 
END
```

**EDIT**

And the multiple symbol version

```
CREATE FUNCTION getSelected2
(    
)
RETURNS @res TABLE 
(
    id int, EntryTime DATETIME, ResultTime DATETIME, Symbol char(3)
)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @idC int;
    declare @ResultTimeC DATETIME;
    declare @EntryTimeC DATETIME;
    declare @SymbolC char(3);
    declare @lastNextDate DATETIME; 
    declare @lastSymbol char(3);

    DECLARE Iterator CURSOR FAST_FORWARD 
    FOR SELECT id, EntryTime, ResultTime, Symbol FROM dbo.tt2 order by Symbol, EntryTime, id
    OPEN Iterator
    WHILE 1=1 BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM Iterator INTO @idC, @EntryTimeC, @ResultTimeC, @SymbolC
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS < 0 BREAK 

        if(@lastSymbol is null or @lastSymbol <> @SymbolC) begin
            set @lastSymbol = @SymbolC;
            set @lastNextDate = null;
        end;
        if(@lastNextDate is null or @lastNextDate < @EntryTimeC) begin
            set @lastNextDate = @ResultTimeC;
            insert into @res (id, EntryTime, ResultTime, Symbol) values (@idC, @EntryTimeC, @ResultTimeC, @SymbolC);
        end;            
    END
    CLOSE Iterator
    DEALLOCATE Iterator;

    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: How can I run this function?

Comment: SELECT * FROM getSelected()

Comment: Very nice, Works perfect for single Symbol, But I add another issue that I have for multiple symbols, Look at the comment where ZLK answered.
How can I do it for multiple Symbols that each one start over?

Comment: @TVC I made an edit. Recursive CTE has some advantages over this, but this could be faster. If You can measure that on real data it could be interesting.

Comment: I just checked it. Very fast... amazing, 5 seconds for all symbols. I got the same results like the recursive way. If so, What are the advantages of the recursive over this like you said?

Comment: @TVC It does not need hard coded column types for example, it is just ordinary select, easier to maintain. When used in more complex select it is optimized as part of it. Multistatement function is just black box and when You filter the result, it would calculate all rows of the function on the way. If You need more effective filtering, You have to build it into the function.